# Intel Wireless N Centrino not working

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint

Replaced my RT3090 MINIPCIE car in my laptop with an intel card. RFkill shows my it hard blocked and nothing seems to un block it.

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[   14.156909] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   14.449635] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 op_mode iwldvm
[   14.748424] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   14.748431] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   14.748435] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   14.748439] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
[   14.748757] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   14.756512] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   14.795137] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   15.201105] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Please also provide the `rfkill list` output. What is you notebook’s make and model?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say it is `hard` blocked? The `dmesg` output contains the line

```
 iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio
```

which means it is done via software (by definition!), hence your card is **soft** blocked. The command

```
 rfkill unblock all
```

should solve it.

This may not be persistent, though. If it is **not**, can you please say whether you have the module `hp_wmi` loaded? You find out by means of

```
lsmod | grep wmi
```

If you have no output, then you do **not** have the module loaded. If instead you **do** have it, as `sudo`

```
echo "blacklist hp_wmi" > /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf
```

and then a reboot will solve the problem completely.

Comment: If `rfkill` says it’s hard-blocked, it probably is.

Comment: @DanielB Oh, ok, that sounds right. Did you look into your BIOS settings? That's what *hard-blocked* means.

Comment: Yeah, the wireless is enabled in the bios. I got fed up and swapped it out with a Broadcom 4313 mini pcie sitting in an old HP mini laptop. Now it works perfect. I didn't have to fiddle with nothing.